# perl Inline cpp not working windows 32 bit

Tags: c++, perl, inline

I'm using perl Inline::CPP with this sample code from cpan documentation

```
 use Inline CPP;

print "9 + 16 = ", add(9, 16), "\n";
print "9 - 16 = ", subtract(9, 16), "\n";

__END__
__CPP__

int add(int x, int y) {
  return x + y;
}

int subtract(int x, int y) {
  return x - y;
}
```

The Error Log

```
   C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe C:\strawberry\perl\lib\ExtUtils\xsubpp  -type
 "C:\strawberry\perl\lib\ExtUtils\typemap"  inline_pl_172d.xs > inline_pl_172
sc && C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e mv -- inline_pl_
d.xsc inline_pl_172d.c
Didn't find a 'MODULE ... PACKAGE ... PREFIX' line
g++ -c          -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEX
DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2     -DVERSION=\
00\"    -DXS_VERSION=\"0.00\"  "-IC:\strawberry\perl\lib\CORE"   inline_pl_17
c
inline_pl_172d.xs:28:2: error: 'MODULE' does not name a type
dmake:  Error code 129, while making 'inline_pl_172d.o'

A problem was encountered while attempting to compile and install your Inline
CPP code. The command that failed was:
  dmake > out.make 2>&1

The build directory was:
D:\university\phd\data\datamail\Chordata2\_Inline\build\inline_pl_172d

To debug the problem, cd to the build directory, and inspect the output files

 at D:\university\phd\data\datamail\Chordata2\inline.pl line 0.
        ...propagated at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/Inline/C.pm line 772.
INIT failed--call queue aborted.
```

If the package is not installed well on my machine How to know and fix it ?

Comment: If you can easily port the algorithm to C and achieve greater performance, what's the point in using Perl then?

Comment: @AlexTokarev E.g. using the functionality in a larger perl-based system.

Comment: Just an idea: maybe your script does not end with a newline, so the "MODULE" keyword in the generated XS file is not recognized.

Comment: @SlavenRezic In that case it would be easier to exec a binary and collect its results for further processing, IMHO.

Comment: @AlexTokarev Normally the `Inline::*` modules work quite well and painless. It's probably really just a missing newline here causing the problems.

Comment: @SlavenRezic The whole approach seems dubious to me. If this is a quick hack destined to be run only once, it's easier to throw in more RAM and be done with it; if this is to become a part of a larger system, using a mix of Perl and C will run up the long term maintenance cost for no obvious reason. Again, what's the point? It almost looks like the OP tries to use Perl for the sake of using Perl, instead of solving the problem.

Comment: @AlexTokarev The CPAN is full of C/XS modules. Apparently it seems just to work, and it has its use cases. And regarding the maintenance costs: for example, I have a XS-based module which I wrote in 1999, perl 5.005 was current at this time. Now, with perl 5.18.1, it still compiles and works. Again, the OP experienced just a silly error which an emacs or vi using developer never sees, because these editors make sure that the file ends with a newline.

Comment: @AlexTokarev this is just a function, I already implemented the whole code in perl, but the output of this function is needed for other functions

Comment: @SlavenRezic where to put the new line ?

Comment: To the end of your file. You will get other errors then, but at least the error `Didn't find a 'MODULE ... PACKAGE ... PREFIX' line` won't happen anymore.

Comment: @SlavenRezic I did, still same errors...

Comment: With your original code, I only get an error about an undeclared `XS_unpack_charPtrPtr` function. This is on a Unix system. There are proposals in the Internet (e.g. at perlmonks) how to deal with this error. My suggestion is also to declare private functions using `static`, and if you can, to combine the `nw` and `print_al` functions, to avoid dealing with `char**`. Actually, when doing this change the script compiles and I see some output when running.

Comment: @SlavenRezic I added static keyword to all the functions and merged print_al with nw still getting the updated error log

Comment: The problem is form Inline::CPP it's not working at all Iwill edit the question

Comment: Mariya, it's an issue with the missing newline at the end of the file. I tried now on a Windows 8.1 machine with a fresh StrawberryPerl, and your sample script compiles fine unless a newline is missing at the end. What editor are you using?

Comment: @SlavenRezic notepad++, but same code works if I change it to C instead of CPP

Comment: `Inline::C` is a different module, and maybe does not have this issue.

Comment: @SlavenRezic I pressed Enter at the end of the file many times... still not working

Comment: Can you provide your script somewhere for download, so we can be sure?

Comment: I filed a bug report against Inline::CPP: https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=89839

Comment: @SlavenRezic the behavior is weird and unstable. sometimes it works sometimes doesn't, and this is only on this sample, I think I will not continue using it..

Comment: Inline::CPP 0.46 is out and has the newline issue fixed.

Comment: thank you @SlavenRezic I'll try on my code, but dunno yet if it's possible to deal with strings...

Answer (score 0):

The your code works for me without modification once I installed Inline::CPP from CPAN...

```
c:\Perl>
c:\Perl>perl StackOverflow.pl
Set up gcc environment - 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
9 + 16 = 25
9 - 16 = -7

c:\Perl>
This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2012, Larry Wall

Binary build 1603 [296746] provided by ActiveState http://www.ActiveState.com
Built Mar 13 2013 11:29:21

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.


c:\Perl>
```

This is on a Win7 32 bit system running ActivePerl 5.16.3 multi-thread and Inline::CPP 0.46 using the default install settings in the Inline::CPP module setup. From the looks of things Perl appears to be using GCC 3.4.5 as the module compiler...

```
c:\Perl>gcc -v
Reading specs from C:/Perl/site/lib/auto/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/specs
Configured with: ../gcc-3.4.5-20060117-3/configure --with-gcc --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --enable-threads --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++,f77,ada,objc,java --disable-win32-registry --disable-shared --enable-s
jlj-exceptions --enable-libgcj --disable-java-awt --without-x --enable-java-gc=boehm --disable-libgcj-debug --enable-interpreter --enable-hash-synchronization --enable-libstdcxx-debug
Thread model: win32
gcc version 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)

c:\Perl>
```

The make utility used is dmake 4.11...

```
c:\Perl>dmake -V MAKE_VERSION
dmake.exe - Version 4.11-20080107-SHAY (Windows / MS Visual C++)
Copyright (c) 1990,...,1997 by WTI Corp.

Default Configuration:
        MAXLINELENGTH := 32766
        MAXPROCESSLIMIT := 4
        MAXPROCESS := 1
        .IMPORT .IGNORE: DMAKEROOT
        .MAKEFILES : makefile.mk makefile
        .SOURCE    : .NULL
        DMAKEROOT *= $(ABSMAKECMD:d)startup
        MAKESTARTUP := $(DMAKEROOT)\startup.mk

Please read the NEWS file for the latest release notes.

c:\Perl>
```

Complete Inline::CPP CPAN module install log...

```
c:\Perl>cpan
Set up gcc environment - 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v2.00)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan> install Inline::CPP
Reading 'C:\Perl\cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 28 Oct 2013 11:08:37 GMT
Fetching with LWP:
http://ppm.activestate.com/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Reading 'C:\Perl\cpan\sources\authors\01mailrc.txt.gz'
............................................................................DONE
Fetching with LWP:
http://ppm.activestate.com/CPAN/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Reading 'C:\Perl\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz'
  Database was generated on Tue, 05 Nov 2013 20:53:02 GMT
Warning: This index file is 40 days old.
  Please check the host you chose as your CPAN mirror for staleness.
  I'll continue but problems seem likely to happen.
............................................................................DONE
Fetching with LWP:
http://ppm.activestate.com/CPAN/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Reading 'C:\Perl\cpan\sources\modules\03modlist.data.gz'
............................................................................DONE
Writing C:\Perl\cpan\Metadata
Running install for module 'Inline::CPP'
Running make for D/DA/DAVIDO/Inline-CPP-0.46.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://ppm.activestate.com/CPAN/authors/id/D/DA/DAVIDO/Inline-CPP-0.46.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://ppm.activestate.com/CPAN/authors/id/D/DA/DAVIDO/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for C:\Perl\cpan\sources\authors\id\D\DA\DAVIDO\Inline-CPP-0.46.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache C:\Perl/cpan/build for sizes
...........................................................................-DONE
DEL(1/2): C:\Perl\cpan\build\Math-Polynomial-1.005-ahaC2G
DEL(2/2): C:\Perl\cpan\build\Math-Polynomial-1.005-ahaC2G.yml
Inline-CPP-0.46/
Inline-CPP-0.46/Makefile.PL
Inline-CPP-0.46/META.yml
Inline-CPP-0.46/README
Inline-CPP-0.46/MANIFEST
Inline-CPP-0.46/TESTED
Inline-CPP-0.46/Changes
Inline-CPP-0.46/MANIFEST.SKIP
Inline-CPP-0.46/t/
Inline-CPP-0.46/t/03prefix.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/t/02basic.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/t/14changes.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/t/11rewrite_config.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/t/04charptr.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/t/07perlcritic.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/t/00load_prereqs.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/t/01fn_cans.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/t/10kwalitee.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/t/06fn_regress.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/t/08cppguess.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/t/09pod_coverage.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/t/13version_numbers.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/t/12custom_libs.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/t/05pod.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/Makefile.PL
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/grammar.pm
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/t/
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/t/03inline.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/t/02scope.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/t/10struct.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/t/01nherit.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/t/05virt.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/t/09purevt.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/t/11minhrt.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/t/15stvar.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/t/14const.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/t/00pod_coverage.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/t/16varlst.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/t/13vararg.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/t/12retlst.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/t/17memberarray.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/t/06deflt.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/t/07static.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/t/08anon.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/grammar/t/04const.t
Inline-CPP-0.46/CPP.pm
Inline-CPP-0.46/META.json
Inline-CPP-0.46/lib/
Inline-CPP-0.46/lib/Inline/
Inline-CPP-0.46/lib/Inline/CPP/
Inline-CPP-0.46/lib/Inline/CPP/Config.pm
Inline-CPP-0.46/lib/Inline/CPP.pod

  CPAN.pm: Building D/DA/DAVIDO/Inline-CPP-0.46.tar.gz

Set up gcc environment - 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
Warning: prerequisite Inline version 0.53 not found. at Makefile.PL line 49.
Warning: prerequisite Inline::C version 0.53 not found. at Makefile.PL line 49.
This will configure and build Inline::C++.
What default C++ compiler would you like to use? [C:\Perl\site\bin\g++.exe]
What default libraries would you like to include? [-lstdc++]
Detected <iostream> style headers. ('.h' not needed.)
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite Inline 0.53 not found. We have 0.52.
Warning: prerequisite Inline::C 0.53 not found. We have 0.52.
Writing Makefile for Inline::CPP::grammar
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing Makefile for Inline::CPP
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----       DAVIDO/Inline-CPP-0.46.tar.gz      ----
    Inline::C [requires]
    Inline [requires]
Running make test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module 'Inline::C'
Running make for S/SI/SISYPHUS/Inline-0.53.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://ppm.activestate.com/CPAN/authors/id/S/SI/SISYPHUS/Inline-0.53.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://ppm.activestate.com/CPAN/authors/id/S/SI/SISYPHUS/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for C:\Perl\cpan\sources\authors\id\S\SI\SISYPHUS\Inline-0.53.tar.gz ok
Inline-0.53/
Inline-0.53/C/
Inline-0.53/C/C-Cookbook.pod
Inline-0.53/C/C.pm
Inline-0.53/C/C.pod
Inline-0.53/C/Changes
Inline-0.53/C/lib/
Inline-0.53/C/lib/Inline/
Inline-0.53/C/lib/Inline/C/
Inline-0.53/C/lib/Inline/C/ParseRecDescent.pm
Inline-0.53/C/lib/Inline/C/ParseRegExp.pm
Inline-0.53/C/Makefile.PL
Inline-0.53/C/README
Inline-0.53/C/rt/
Inline-0.53/C/rt/grammars.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/
Inline-0.53/C/t/00init.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/01syntax.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/02config.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/03typemap.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/04perlapi.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/05xsmode.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/06parseregexp.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/07typemap_multi.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/08taint.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/08taint_1.p
Inline-0.53/C/t/08taint_2.p
Inline-0.53/C/t/08taint_3.p
Inline-0.53/C/t/09parser.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/10callback.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/11default_readonly.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/12taint_old.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/14void_arg.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/15ccflags.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/16ccflagsex.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/17prehead.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/18quote_space.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/19INC.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/20eval.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/21read_DATA.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/22read_DATA_2.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/23validate.t
Inline-0.53/C/t/bar/
Inline-0.53/C/t/bar/find_me_in_bar.h
Inline-0.53/C/t/foo/
Inline-0.53/C/t/foo/find_me_in_foo.h
Inline-0.53/C/t/prehead.in
Inline-0.53/C/t/soldier_typemap
Inline-0.53/C/t/typemap
Inline-0.53/Changes
Inline-0.53/Inline-API.pod
Inline-0.53/Inline-FAQ.pod
Inline-0.53/Inline-Support.pod
Inline-0.53/Inline.pm
Inline-0.53/Inline.pod
Inline-0.53/kobes.log
Inline-0.53/lib/
Inline-0.53/lib/Inline/
Inline-0.53/lib/Inline/denter.pm
Inline-0.53/lib/Inline/Foo.pm
Inline-0.53/lib/Inline/MakeMaker/
Inline-0.53/lib/Inline/MakeMaker/Changes
Inline-0.53/lib/Inline/MakeMaker.pm
Inline-0.53/Makefile.PL
Inline-0.53/MANIFEST
Inline-0.53/modules/
Inline-0.53/modules/Math/
Inline-0.53/modules/Math/Simple/
Inline-0.53/modules/Math/Simple/Changes
Inline-0.53/modules/Math/Simple/Makefile.PL
Inline-0.53/modules/Math/Simple/MANIFEST
Inline-0.53/modules/Math/Simple/Simple.pm
Inline-0.53/modules/Math/Simple/test.pl
Inline-0.53/README
Inline-0.53/symbols.perl
Inline-0.53/t/
Inline-0.53/t/00init.t
Inline-0.53/t/01usages.t
Inline-0.53/t/02config.t
Inline-0.53/t/03errors.t
Inline-0.53/t/04create.t
Inline-0.53/t/05files.t
Inline-0.53/t/06rewrite_config.p
Inline-0.53/t/06rewrite_config.t
Inline-0.53/t/07rewrite2_config.p
Inline-0.53/t/07rewrite2_config.t
Inline-0.53/t/file
Inline-0.53/ToDo

  CPAN.pm: Building S/SI/SISYPHUS/Inline-0.53.tar.gz

Set up gcc environment - 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good

Inline::C is packaged with Inline.pm because it is the most commonly used
Inline Language Support Module (ILSM).

See also: Inline::ASM, ::Awk, ::BC, ::Basic, ::Befunge, ::CPP (C++), ::CPR,
          ::Foo, ::Guile, ::Java, ::Octave, ::PERL, ::Python, ::Ruby, ::TT,
          ::Tcl and ::WebChat.

Config.pm indicates that your version of Perl was built with this C compiler:

    C:\Perl\site\bin\gcc.exe

I have located this compiler on your system.

Do you want to install Inline::C? [y] y
Writing Makefile for Inline::C
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing Makefile for Inline
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Fixing Makefile for MSWin32
cp Inline.pod blib\lib\Inline.pod
cp lib/Inline/MakeMaker/Changes blib\lib\Inline\MakeMaker\Changes
cp lib/Inline/denter.pm blib\lib\Inline\denter.pm
AutoSplitting blib\lib\Inline\denter.pm (blib\lib\auto\Inline\denter)
cp Inline.pm blib\lib\Inline.pm
AutoSplitting blib\lib\Inline.pm (blib\lib\auto\Inline)
cp lib/Inline/Foo.pm blib\lib\Inline\Foo.pm
cp Inline-API.pod blib\lib\Inline-API.pod
cp lib/Inline/MakeMaker.pm blib\lib\Inline\MakeMaker.pm
cp Inline-FAQ.pod blib\lib\Inline-FAQ.pod
cp Inline-Support.pod blib\lib\Inline-Support.pod
cp lib/Inline/C/ParseRegExp.pm ..\blib\lib\Inline\C\ParseRegExp.pm
cp C-Cookbook.pod ..\blib\lib\Inline\C-Cookbook.pod
cp C.pm ..\blib\lib\Inline\C.pm
cp C.pod ..\blib\lib\Inline\C.pod
cp lib/Inline/C/ParseRecDescent.pm ..\blib\lib\Inline\C\ParseRecDescent.pm
  SISYPHUS/Inline-0.53.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe -- OK
Running make test
C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/00init.t ............. ok
t/01usages.t ........... ok
t/02config.t ........... ok
t/03errors.t ........... ok
t/04create.t ........... ok
t/05files.t ............ ok
t/06rewrite_config.t ... ok
t/07rewrite2_config.t .. ok
All tests successful.
Files=8, Tests=19, 15 wallclock secs ( 0.11 usr +  0.06 sys =  0.17 CPU)
Result: PASS
C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, '..\blib\lib', '..\blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/00init.t .............. ok
t/01syntax.t ............ ok
t/02config.t ............ ok
t/03typemap.t ........... ok
t/04perlapi.t ........... ok
t/05xsmode.t ............ ok
t/06parseregexp.t ....... ok
t/07typemap_multi.t ..... ok
t/08taint.t ............. ok
t/09parser.t ............
This test could take a couple of minutes to run
t/09parser.t ............ ok
t/10callback.t .......... ok
t/11default_readonly.t .. ok
t/12taint_old.t ......... Skipped - applies only to perl 5.6.x
t/12taint_old.t ......... ok
t/14void_arg.t .......... ok
t/15ccflags.t ........... ok
t/16ccflagsex.t ......... ok
t/17prehead.t ........... ok
t/18quote_space.t ....... ok
t/19INC.t ............... ok
t/20eval.t .............. ok
t/21read_DATA.t ......... ok
t/22read_DATA_2.t ....... ok
t/23validate.t .......... ok
All tests successful.
Files=23, Tests=71, 165 wallclock secs ( 0.12 usr +  0.05 sys =  0.17 CPU)
Result: PASS
  SISYPHUS/Inline-0.53.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe test -- OK
Running make install
Prepending C:\Perl\cpan\build\Inline-0.53-JPPUvK/blib/arch C:\Perl\cpan\build\Inline-0.53-JPPUvK/blib/lib to PERL5LIB for 'install'
Installing C:\Perl\site\lib\Inline.pm
Installing C:\Perl\site\lib\Inline.pod
Installing C:\Perl\site\lib\Inline\C.pm
Installing C:\Perl\site\lib\Inline\MakeMaker.pm
Installing C:\Perl\site\lib\Inline\MakeMaker\Changes
Appending installation info to C:\Perl\lib/perllocal.pod
  SISYPHUS/Inline-0.53.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe install  -- OK
Inline is up to date (0.53).
Running make for D/DA/DAVIDO/Inline-CPP-0.46.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory C:\Perl\cpan\build\Inline-CPP-0.46-QMmSMq

  CPAN.pm: Building D/DA/DAVIDO/Inline-CPP-0.46.tar.gz

cp lib/Inline/CPP/Config.pm blib\lib\Inline\CPP\Config.pm
cp CPP.pm blib\lib\Inline\CPP.pm
cp lib/Inline/CPP.pod blib\lib\Inline\CPP.pod
cp grammar.pm ..\blib\lib\Inline\CPP\grammar.pm
  DAVIDO/Inline-CPP-0.46.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe -- OK
Running make test
C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/00load_prereqs.t ..... # $Config{osname}:     MSWin32
# $Config{cc}:         C:\Perl\site\bin\gcc.exe
# $Config{gccversion}: 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
t/00load_prereqs.t ..... ok
t/01fn_cans.t .......... ok
t/02basic.t ............ ok
t/03prefix.t ........... ok
t/04charptr.t .......... ok
t/05pod.t .............. skipped: Author Test: Set $ENV{RELEASE_TESTING} to a true value to run.
t/06fn_regress.t ....... ok
t/07perlcritic.t ....... skipped: Author Test: Set $ENV{RELEASE_TESTING} to a true value to run.
t/08cppguess.t ......... # ExtUtils::CppGuess not installed.  This set of tests and diagnostics
# is more thorough when ExtUtils::CppGuess can be loaded.
# Detected basic defaults (Strawberry, etc.).
#
# Compiler guess:
t/08cppguess.t ......... 1/2 #  Makefile.PL approach: [C:\Perl\site\bin\g++.exe].
#
# Linker guess:
#       Makefile.PL approach: [-lstdc++].
t/08cppguess.t ......... ok
t/09pod_coverage.t ..... skipped: Author Test: Set $ENV{RELEASE_TESTING} to a true value to run.
t/10kwalitee.t ......... skipped: Author Test: Set $ENV{RELEASE_TESTING} to a true value to run.
t/11rewrite_config.t ... skipped: Author Test: Set $ENV{RELEASE_TESTING} to a true value to run.
t/12custom_libs.t ...... ok
t/13version_numbers.t .. skipped: Author Test: Set $ENV{RELEASE_TESTING} to a true value to run.
t/14changes.t .......... skipped: Author tests skipped.  Set $ENV{RELEASE_TESTING} to run
All tests successful.
Files=15, Tests=29, 22 wallclock secs ( 0.09 usr +  0.05 sys =  0.14 CPU)
Result: PASS
C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, '..\blib\lib', '..\blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/00pod_coverage.t .. ok
t/01nherit.t ........ ok
t/02scope.t ......... ok
t/03inline.t ........ ok
t/04const.t ......... ok
t/05virt.t .......... ok
t/06deflt.t ......... ok
t/07static.t ........ ok
t/08anon.t .......... ok
t/09purevt.t ........ ok
t/10struct.t ........ ok
t/11minhrt.t ........ ok
t/12retlst.t ........ ok
t/13vararg.t ........ ok
t/14const.t ......... ok
t/15stvar.t ......... ok
t/16varlst.t ........ ok
t/17memberarray.t ... ok
All tests successful.

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/11minhrt.t      (Wstat: 0 Tests: 38 Failed: 0)
  TODO passed:   28-31
Files=18, Tests=79, 89 wallclock secs ( 0.14 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.14 CPU)
Result: PASS
  DAVIDO/Inline-CPP-0.46.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe test -- OK
Running make install
Prepending C:\Perl\cpan\build\Inline-CPP-0.46-QMmSMq/blib/arch C:\Perl\cpan\build\Inline-CPP-0.46-QMmSMq/blib/lib to PERL5LIB for 'install'
Installing C:\Perl\site\lib\Inline\CPP.pm
Installing C:\Perl\site\lib\Inline\CPP.pod
Installing C:\Perl\site\lib\Inline\CPP\Config.pm
Installing C:\Perl\site\lib\Inline\CPP\grammar.pm
Appending installation info to C:\Perl\lib/perllocal.pod
  DAVIDO/Inline-CPP-0.46.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe install  -- OK

cpan> exit
Lockfile removed.

c:\Perl>
```

Hopes this helps.